# unable to find Windows files using Ubuntu

Tags: windows, files, partitioning

I'm using a Samsung rv520 i3. Windows 7 crashed and fails to load past the initial windows logo screen. I am now using Ubuntu 12.10 from a USB.

I'm trying to find files I had saved on Windows before Windows crashed.

My problem is I can't find the files or windows partition anywhere. I'm not really competent using linux systems and using terminals so its not really that surprising.

Answer (score 2):

On the filemanager under "Devices" you will probably find your windows partions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hit f8 try booting into safe mode and disable everything non m$$ by using msconfig, type that into run.

fdisk -l will list all partitions.

Answer (score 0):

No problem, what you might be looking for is your "c:" drive, right? You might want to poke around in "Volumen van 444 GB" (language?? -curious) and look for documents and settings, your windows user name, and look in there depending on your document,download,file location) that is a good start at least....

Comment: My windows and ubuntu installation are dutch. But it means "partion of 444gb". if windows was english it should be "444 gb filesystem".